# Sublime text gives all in one line

Tags: php, sublimetext2

Yesterday I detected a problem. The sublime text 2 sometimes puts all the code to the one line only. It's a problem, because in PHP code i have a comment starting with // and it means, that all the line is a comment... Can somebody help me, how can I disable this one line problem?

Answer (score 0):

Often if you don't pre-save a file as .php or whatever the file extension is that you are using, Sublime Text 2 will not know what to do with the spaces, tabs, etc. and throw everything in one line.  If you are pre-saving your file, then I'm not sure what's wrong.